# mat-selection-list with nested for loop in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

The dataset I'm getting in my API is as following:

| product name | category | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone | Smart Phone | 3 |
| iPhone | Apple | 3 |
| Motorola | Smart Phone | 4 |

How I want to show this is like Product Name as header then Categories of the product belongs to and then review:

[image: Product name then categories]

There should be only one entry for each product and all the categories for that should be comma separated below that.

I'm using
`mat-selection-list` and my code look like this:

```js
<div class="products-box">
        <mat-selection-list #products color="primary">
          <mat-list-option
            class="p-1 m-1"
            checkboxPosition="before"
            *ngFor="let product of products"
          >
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                {{ product.name }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
               {{ product.rating }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-muted">{{ product.category }}</div>
            </div>
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
      </div>
```

How should I write nested for loop so I get comma separated categories for each product?

Comment: Can you describe more, please?

Comment: When I'm using above code, I'm getting two entries for iPhone. One for each category. What I want is for each product one entry and categories should be comma separated.. as shown in image.

Comment: Can you create this example on stackblitz, it would be very easier for every one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a minimum working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8qyfhk) which uses Lodash's `groupBy` function to group the list of products by the `productName`. This method has the benefit of only requiring the grouping logic to be undertaken once when the page loads for the first time.

#### Models

```js
export interface ProductCategoryRanking {
  productName: string;
  category: string;
  rating: number;
}
```

#### Services

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ProductCategoryRanking } from "./product-category-ranking";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ProductCategoryRankingService {
  get(): ProductCategoryRanking[] {
    return [
      {
        productName: "iPhone",
        category: "Smart Phone",
        rating: 3
      },
      {
        productName: "iPhone",
        category: "Apple",
        rating: 3
      },
      {
        productName: "Motorola",
        category: "Smart Phone",
        rating: 4
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

#### Components

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import _ from "lodash";
import { ProductCategoryRanking } from "./product-category-ranking";
import { ProductCategoryRankingService } from "./product-category-ranking.service";

/**
 * @title List with selection
 */
@Component({
  selector: "list-selection-example",
  styleUrls: ["list-selection-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "list-selection-example.html"
})
export class ListSelectionExample implements OnInit {
  productCategoryRankings: _.Dictionary<ProductCategoryRanking[]>;

  constructor(
    private productCategoryRankingService: ProductCategoryRankingService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productCategoryRankings = _.groupBy(
      this.productCategoryRankingService.get(),
      "productName"
    );
  }

  getCategory(productCategoryRankings: ProductCategoryRanking[]): string {
    return productCategoryRankings.map(value => value.category).join(", ");
  }

  getRating(productCategoryRankings: ProductCategoryRanking[]): number {
    return productCategoryRankings.map(value => value.rating)[0];
  }
}

/**  Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

```html
<mat-selection-list #values color="primary">
  <mat-list-option
    *ngFor="let kvp of productCategoryRankings | keyvalue"
    class="p-1 m-1"
    checkboxPosition="before"
  >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        {{ kvp.key }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        {{ getRating(kvp.value) }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-muted">
        {{ getCategory(kvp.value) }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<p>
  Options selected: {{ values.selectedOptions.selected.length }}
</p>

<!-- Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```